# Animation using simple canvas in a View

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-canvas, android-view

I am trying to form a simple animation (At the moment nothing more than drawing some lines) in a `View` using mono for android.

Here is my code:

```
public class DemoView : View
{
    public DemoView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) :
        base(context, attrs)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public DemoView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) :
        base(context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnDraw(Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);

        canvas.DrawColor(Color.Blue);

        Paint pen = new Paint();

        pen.Color = Color.Red;
        pen.StrokeWidth = 2;
        pen.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);

        canvas.DrawLine(0, 0, 25, 25, pen);
    }

    //How to add other lines to form an animation?
}
```

The code above just renders background in blue color and draws a line. I am looking for methods ( I beleive something like `OnPaint` so that I can draw some lines while the application is open. I really do not know what too look for.

Comment: at the end of the `OnDraw` call `invalidate` and the view will be drawn again. Draw different things to create an animation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [MonoDroid samples project](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples) on github. It's a comprehensive resource for how to implement different Android solutions with MonoDroid.

It contains several example apps that use drawing of animations including a [Snake game](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/Snake) and a [Live Wallpaper](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/LiveWallpaperDemo).

Answer (score 2):

this is what my `OnDraw` method looks like

```
protected override void OnDraw(Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
{
    base.OnDraw(canvas);

    if (x < 0 && y < 0)
    {
        x = Width/2;
        y = Height/2;
    }
    else
    {
        x += xVelocity;
        y += yVelocity;

        if (x > Width - particleWidth || x < 0)
            xVelocity *= -1;
        if (y > Height - particleHeight || y < 0)
            yVelocity *= -1;
    }

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.Color = Color.White;
    canvas.DrawCircle(x, y, particleWidth, p);
    handler.PostDelayed(Invalidate, FRAME_RATE);
}
```

`handler.PostDelayed` was the one responsible for timer

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the Timer class. It can schedule your TimerTask (Override the run() method) and run it at regular intervals. After that you can call postInvalidate() in the run() method. This method will call the onDraw() method and all your Canvas drawing can be done in that method. This is assuming this is not your UI class otherwise call invalidate().

```
    public DrawView(Context context, VoiceGraphActivity _parent) {
    super(context);
    parent_ = _parent;

    paintBorder.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    paintBorder.setColor(0xff888870);
    paintBorder.setAlpha(170);

    paintGraph.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    paintGraph.setColor(0xff888888);
    paintGraph.setAlpha(230);

    timer = new Timer();

    class liveGraph extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            postInvalidate ();
        }

    };

    int UI_UPDATE_MS = 100;

    timer.schedule(new liveGraph(), UI_UPDATE_MS, UI_UPDATE_MS);
}
```

You can try to add touch events in the run method. This code is from a Graphing application I am working on. It constantly records the sound from MIC and draws the amplitude in two seperate thread.